# Running 2 real android devices in parallel using Appium

Tags: java, selenium, appium, android-testing

I'm new with Appium and trying to run 2 android devices using Appium and Selenium (Java) parallel but only 1 device is running my test script. Below is my test script (junit) and having hard time trying to work this out. I'm not using any Grid or Cloud Grid (SauceLabs/BrowserStack) for the mean time as I'd like to monitor this locally for now.

```
public class StartChrome {

public WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "Appium");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.0");
    capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Phone's Name");

    URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, capabilities);
}

@Test
public void test() {
    driver.get("http://saucelabs.com/test/guinea-pig");

    WebElement div = driver.findElement(By.id("i_am_an_id"));
    Assert.assertEquals("I am a div", div.getText());
    driver.findElement(By.id("comments")).sendKeys("My comment");
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
}
```

I'm not really sure what details I need to add here but I'm happy to answer anything and and advice would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you find the solution?if yes, please do share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You need to start two appium servers on diffrent ports. Then you use that URL for both of your scripts and run them in parallel using TesNg.